# UITableView editing mode

Tags: uitableview

I am doing things within the edit mode of `UITableView` using `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` or `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`.

It works rather well, but there one thing I tried with no success.
I tried the following, using the bitwise or operator:

```
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert|UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
```

hoping to return to return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` and `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` at the same time.

I do not see why it should not be possible. I would just mean that I want to be able to delete the cell and I also want to be able to insert one other cell before.
But how about the reality?
Am I missing some point?

Comment: `UITableViewCell` will not have more than one editing style. I think Apple set this by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design, a cell can only have one editing style. Besides the controls are placed in the same location. Also the way the enum is defined:

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert
} UITableViewCellEditingStyle;
```

It's not designed for ORing like some option enums are, for example the `UIViewAutoResizingMask` from `UIView`:

```
enum {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

Comment: I see. Well, if that is the way it is. We'll have to live with it. Thanks.